# Updating a UIView with a subview's gesture handler

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, setneedsdisplay

I have a simple app with a single `ViewController` containing a very minimal view hierarchy: `DrawingView` (a subclass of `UIView`), and three `ImageViews` (which are each children of `DrawingView`).

Inside `DrawingView`, I've overridden `draw(_:)` to produce graphics which depend on the center of each `ImageView` (specifically, a polygon whose vertices are the image centers). Meanwhile, the `ImageView` positions are controlled by the user through drag gestures. The gesture handling action is a method of `ViewController`.

I'd like for `DrawingView` to update in real-time as the `ImageView` positions change. To accomplish this, I've called `DrawingView.setNeedsDisplay()` inside the gesture handler. However, this approach only updates `DrawingView` discretely, and seemingly not until the next gesture begins (regardless of where the call appears in the `switch gesture.state` statement).

[image: simulator screengrab]

**My question**: where/how should I call `setNeedsDisplay` in order to achieve a smooth (and real-time) update to `DrawingView`? Or is there a better approach?

Here are my class definitions:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var drawingView: DrawingView!

    @IBOutlet var majorVertex1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var majorVertex2: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var majorVertex3: UIImageView!
    
    var majorVertices: [UIImageView]!
    
    @IBOutlet var majorVertex1XConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var majorVertex1YConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var majorVertex2XConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var majorVertex2YConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var majorVertex3XConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var majorVertex3YConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    var majorVertexXConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]!
    var majorVertexYConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]!
    
    static var majorVertexXOffsets: [Double]?
    static var majorVertexYOffsets: [Double]?
        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        majorVertices = [majorVertex1, majorVertex2, majorVertex3]
        majorVertexXConstraints = [majorVertex1XConstraint, majorVertex2XConstraint, majorVertex3XConstraint]
        majorVertexYConstraints = [majorVertex1YConstraint, majorVertex2YConstraint, majorVertex3YConstraint]
        ViewController.majorVertexXOffsets = majorVertexXConstraints.map {(constraint) -> Double in return constraint.constant}
        ViewController.majorVertexYOffsets = majorVertexYConstraints.map {(constraint) -> Double in return constraint.constant}
        
    }

    @IBAction func handlePan(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        
        guard let majorVertices = majorVertices,
              let gestureView = gesture.view
        else {return}
        
        guard let parentView = gestureView.superview,
              let gestureViewIndex = majorVertices.firstIndex(of: gestureView as! UIImageView)
        else {return}
        
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: parentView)
        
        switch gesture.state {
            
        case .began:
            ViewController.majorVertexXOffsets = majorVertexXConstraints.map {(constraint) -> Double in return constraint.constant}
            ViewController.majorVertexYOffsets = majorVertexYConstraints.map {(constraint) -> Double in return constraint.constant}
            break
            
        case .changed:
            majorVertexXConstraints[gestureViewIndex].constant = ViewController.majorVertexXOffsets![gestureViewIndex] + translation.x
            majorVertexYConstraints[gestureViewIndex].constant = ViewController.majorVertexYOffsets![gestureViewIndex] + translation.y
            drawingView.setNeedsDisplay()
            break
            
        case .ended, .cancelled:
            majorVertexXConstraints[gestureViewIndex].constant = gestureView.center.x - parentView.frame.size.width / 2.0
            majorVertexYConstraints[gestureViewIndex].constant = gestureView.center.y - parentView.frame.size.height / 2.0
            break

        default:
            break
            
        }
        
    }

}


class DrawingView: UIView {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }
    
    func setupView() {
        backgroundColor = .clear
    }
        
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        drawTriangle(rect)
    }
    
    internal func drawTriangle(_ rect: CGRect) {
        
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),
              let majorVertexXOffsets = ViewController.majorVertexXOffsets,
              let majorVertexYOffsets = ViewController.majorVertexYOffsets
        else {return}
        
        let majorVertexXCenters = majorVertexXOffsets.map {(x) -> Double in return x + rect.width / 2.0}
        let majorVertexYCenters = majorVertexYOffsets.map {(y) -> Double in return y + rect.height / 2.0}
                
        context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.lightGray.cgColor)
        context.setLineWidth(3)
        
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: majorVertexXCenters[0], y: majorVertexYCenters[0]))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: majorVertexXCenters[1], y: majorVertexYCenters[1]))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: majorVertexXCenters[2], y: majorVertexYCenters[2]))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: majorVertexXCenters[0], y: majorVertexYCenters[0]))
        
        context.strokePath()
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing some rather funky things with `static` vars, which require direct referencing to the specific class... and, it's not entirely clear how you've setup your constraints relative to the views, but...

The reason you are not seeing "real-time" draw updates is because you change the constraint **constants** without updating the X & Y **offsets** arrays.

```
    case .changed:
        // modify constraint constants to "move" the view
        majorVertexXConstraints[gestureViewIndex].constant = ViewController.majorVertexXOffsets![gestureViewIndex] + translation.x
        majorVertexYConstraints[gestureViewIndex].constant = ViewController.majorVertexYOffsets![gestureViewIndex] + translation.y

        // update the arrays of X/Y offsets
        ViewController.majorVertexXOffsets = majorVertexXConstraints.map {(constraint) -> Double in return constraint.constant}
        ViewController.majorVertexYOffsets = majorVertexYConstraints.map {(constraint) -> Double in return constraint.constant}

        // NOW call setNeedsDisplay()
        drawingView.setNeedsDisplay()

        // because we're now updating the constraint constants on .changed
        // we need to reset the gesture translation
        gesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: parentView)
        
        break
```

---

**Edit** - *in response to comment...*

The approach you've taken with `static` vars results in what's referred to as "Tight Coupling" -- where two or more classes are heavily dependent on each other, which can make it difficult to change and/or reuse the classes.

The issue has too much depth to fully discuss here, but a quick example:

In your `DrawingView` class, you have these two lines:

```
let majorVertexXOffsets = ViewController.majorVertexXOffsets
let majorVertexYOffsets = ViewController.majorVertexYOffsets
```

Suppose you want to use `DrawingView` in `SomeOtherController`? You have to edit those two lines:

```
let majorVertexXOffsets = SomeOtherController.majorVertexXOffsets
let majorVertexYOffsets = SomeOtherController.majorVertexYOffsets
```

and now `DrawingView` no longer works in the original `ViewController`.

What you want to do instead is to add var properties to `DrawingView` and set/update them as needed.

So, in `ViewController` remove the `static` keyword:

```
//static var majorVertexXOffsets: [Double]?
//static var majorVertexYOffsets: [Double]?
var majorVertexXOffsets: [Double]?
var majorVertexYOffsets: [Double]?
```

then remove all occurrences of `ViewController.` in your code:

```
//ViewController.majorVertexXOffsets
majorVertexXOffsets
```

Next we add two properties to `DrawingView`:

```
var majorVertexXOffsets: [Double]?
var majorVertexYOffsets: [Double]?
```

and, change the first part of `drawTriangle()`:

```
//guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),
//      let majorVertexXOffsets = ViewController.majorVertexXOffsets,
//      let majorVertexYOffsets = ViewController.majorVertexYOffsets
//else {return}
    
guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),
      let majorVertexXOffsets = majorVertexXOffsets,
      let majorVertexYOffsets = majorVertexYOffsets
else {return}
```

The last step is back in `ViewController`:

```
    case .changed:
        // modify constraint constants to "move" the view
        majorVertexXConstraints[gestureViewIndex].constant = majorVertexXOffsets![gestureViewIndex] + translation.x
        majorVertexYConstraints[gestureViewIndex].constant = majorVertexYOffsets![gestureViewIndex] + translation.y
        
        // update the arrays of X/Y offsets
        majorVertexXOffsets = majorVertexXConstraints.map {(constraint) -> Double in return constraint.constant}
        majorVertexYOffsets = majorVertexYConstraints.map {(constraint) -> Double in return constraint.constant}

        // NEW \/           
        // update the X/Y offset arrays in drawingView
        drawingView.majorVertexXOffsets = majorVertexXOffsets
        drawingView.majorVertexYOffsets = majorVertexYOffsets
        // NEW /\           
        
        // NOW call setNeedsDisplay()
        drawingView.setNeedsDisplay()
        
        // reset the gesture translation
        gesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: parentView)
        
        break
```

Search for `Tight Coupling Anti-Pattern` for more in-depth discussion.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks for pointing that out! Regarding the static variables...I'm really brand new to this stuff, and that was the only way I figured out how to access variables defined in `ViewController`. Suggestions? TIA

Comment: @vonbecker - see the **Edit** to my answer.